# Allocating a contiguous sequence not working

Tags: c, pointers, shared-memory, memory-address

I am working with shared memory and hence I need to attach some portion of the memory to some other process.
I am trying to attach to a contiguous sequence, but this does not seem to work after the integer and the float arrays.
Here NUMBER_OF_DATA=5

```
int shmid=shmget(key,size,0777|IPC_CREAT);
  int *a=(int *)shmat(shmid,0,0);
  float *b=(float *)(a+NUMBER_OF_DATA);
  char *array1[20];
array1[0]=(char *)(b+NUMBER_OF_DATA);
  char *array2[20];
array2[0]=(char *)(array1+(20*NUMBER_OF_DATA));
  for(i=0;i<NUMBER_OF_DATA;i++)
    {
      a[i]=roll_no[i];
      b[i]=cgpa[i];
      array1[i]=firstname[i];
      array2[i]=lastname[i];
    printf("%p %p %p %p\n",&a[i],&b[i],&array1[i],&array2[i]);
    }
```

When I print the addresses, I get

```
0xb777d000 0xb777d014 0xbfd480a0 0xbfd480f0
0xb777d004 0xb777d018 0xbfd480a4 0xbfd480f4
0xb777d008 0xb777d01c 0xbfd480a8 0xbfd480f8
0xb777d00c 0xb777d020 0xbfd480ac 0xbfd480fc
0xb777d010 0xb777d024 0xbfd480b0 0xbfd48100
```

which is not continuous after the arrays a and b. Why is this so? What is the solution?

Comment: @thejh sorry, edited the question, its 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only initializing the first field of `array1` and `array2`, the rest is uninitialized. You seem to have confused something, but I'm not sure what you exact intention is here.

If you want the two arrays to be `char *`s, it's simple, do it like you did it for the ints and floats.

However, if you really want something like a `char*[]`, you need to store not just the values, but also the pointers to the values in the shared memory segment.

Comment: I want to store two string arrays array1 and array2. So they are 2D arrays. How to I attach allocate them to the shared memory and attach to it?

Comment: You need to first allocate the array: `char **array=(char**)(b+NUMBER_OF_DATA)` and then copy over all the strings into the shared memory segment: `char *mempos = (char *)(array+NUMBER_OF_DATA); for (int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_DATA; i++) { array[i] = mempos; strcpy(array[i], firstname[i]); mempos+=strlen(array[i]+1); }`
However, note that you'll be unable to resize the strings afterwards!

Comment: is this correct char *mempos = (char *)(array+NUMBER_OF_DATA); ? what will it do?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working. But could you please explain the function of char *mempos = (char *)(array+NUMBER_OF_DATA);

Comment: `mempos` contains the address to which the strings should be copied. Initially, that address is directly behind the string array.

Comment: Directly behind the string array? I need to start from the begginning right?

Comment: I am not able to understand the use of array+NUMBER_OF_DATA. Also when I remove this NUMBER_OF_DATA, i should get the same address as array, but i get the address as (address of array + 4)bytes. Why? I am totally confused

Answer (score 0):

Seems like in this line

```
  array1[i]=firstname[i];
  array2[i]=lastname[i];
```

you are overwriting your values of `array[i]` so it is no longer a pointer to some part of your shared memory, as it was in

```
array1[0]=(char *)(b+NUMBER_OF_DATA);
array2[0]=(char *)(array1+(20*NUMBER_OF_DATA));
```

In the last two columns of your output you are actually printing the value of `firstname[i]`, not of `(char *)(b+NUMBER_OF_DATA)`. If it is unintentional, then it is the answer. If it is not, well, knowing what this `firstname` and `lastname` variable are will be useful for us to give better answer.

**UPD:** Also note that at i ≥ 0 you are printing uninitialized items of array1 and array2.